# A PrintStream that does nothing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, printstream

I am trying to make a `PrintStream` that does nothing every time its methods are invoked. The code has no error apparently, but when I try to use it I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Null output stream`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DoNothingPrintStream extends PrintStream {
    
    public static final DoNothingPrintStream doNothingPrintStream = new DoNothingPrintStream();

    private static final OutputStream support = new OutputStream() {
        public void write(int b) {}
    };
    // ======================================================
        // TODO | Constructor
    
    /** Creates a new {@link DoNothingPrintStream}.
     * 
     */
    private DoNothingPrintStream() {
        super( support );
        if( support == null )
            System.out.println("DoNothingStream has null support");
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Please  include the full error message with the complete stack trace.

Comment: I think you have an infinite recursion here, as your `DoNothingPrintStream` class creates inside itself another object of the same class, which will continue recursively until you are out of memory

Comment: You are writing in an output stream which is null, Could you please try initialize the variable b and pass something to it.

Comment: Remove this line `public static final DoNothingPrintStream doNothingPrintStream = new DoNothingPrintStream();` and retry. If you want it to be singleton, then change the assignment to `null` an add a `getInstance` method that will create the instance.

Comment: @SomethingSomething it's static, so it wouldn't be infinite recursion? Since there is 1 class, and 1 instance tied to that class. Not an instance tied to each instance.

Comment: @matt right, it's static, I didn't notice, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the initialisation order. Static fields are initialised in the order that you have declared them ("textual order"), so `doNothingPrintStream` is initialised before `support`.

When `doNothingPrintStream = new DoNothingPrintStream();` is executing, `support` has not been initialised yet, because its declaration is after the declaration of `doNothingPrintStream`. This is why in the constructor, `support` is null.

Your "support is null" message doesn't get printed, because the exception got thrown (at the `super()` call) before it could be printed.

Just switch around the orders of the declarations:

```
private static final OutputStream support = new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {}
};

public static final DoNothingPrintStream doNothingPrintStream = new DoNothingPrintStream();
```